# iPad physical orientation doesn't have any effect

Tags: html, ipad, orientation

I understand that "portrait" iPad orientation corresponds to a window 1024px wide, and 768px for "landscape".

However I have always the same width regardless of my iPad orientation when I visit my web page.

At the left bottom, the number in red color represents the value of `jQuery('body').width()`connected to the `resize()` JS event. Why does the value remain the same in both portrait and landscape modes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `initial-scale=1` to your meta `viewport` tag. See this related question: [Viewport meta tag for iOS devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892809/viewport-meta-tag-for-ios-devices)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jQuery to change the style of your page you should consider using Sass Media Queries.

http://thesassway.com/intermediate/responsive-web-design-in-sass-using-media-queries-in-sass-32

http://thesassway.com/intermediate/responsive-web-design-part-2

It is simpler and doesn't rely on js events and code manipulation.

Hope it helps,
Cheers.