# Viewport - width=device-width on iPad

Tags: html, ipad, media-queries

I have this set:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

On an iPhone it works, the webpage is the width of the device.

On an iPad, in portrait the page is wider than the screen, it works find in landscape mode.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

Fix will be

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
```

refer this

[Viewport meta tag for iOS devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892809/viewport-meta-tag-for-ios-devices)

Comment: This does not fix the issue.